# Why my Azure Web App Service has HEAD request fail log in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I'm wondering this specific azure web app have this failed HTTP HEAD requests while the other azure web apps that have the same configuration and share the codes didn't have this log.

NOTE: My web app services are built with ASP.NET Core.

Other details failed request.

resultCode: 404

operation_Name: HEAD /

cloud_RoleInstance: RD0003FFEE5DF0

[image: Log]

Comment: Was this some sort of attack?

Comment: Could you please post more details information about this request? About who send the request and the url. It seems some kind of attack.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I investigated and checked the logs, it is from unknown so I thought it was from the application gateway requests but with further investigation, the web app service URL was used so maybe someone in our internal developers has caused this.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

Something is making requests to your API to the root path (/) using the 'HEAD' method, and likely there is no controller mapped to '/'.  This is usually used for health checks, verify you don't have a gateway or balancer probing your API.